# Proof of an L^2 and L^1 inequality

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to prove the following statement as part of an undergraduate analysis course,

> Show that if $f \in L^2([a,b])$, then there exists a constant $C > 0$ (not dependent on $f$), such that $||f||_1 \leq C ||f||_2$

But I'm struggling to find where to start, I began by writing the statement out in terms of integrals,
$$
\int_a^b{|f(x)|\,dx} \leq C \sqrt{\int_a^b{|f(x)|^2\,dx}},
$$
but I am unsure of where to go from here, I have a feeling it's something to do with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I just can't quite seem to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a square root around the right-hand integral. Also, as a hint, you're on the right track with Cauchy-Schwarz - now consider the function $g(x) = 1$.

Comment: $|f(x)|$ is product of $1$ and $|f(x)|$. Just aply Cauchy-Schwarz.